# How many optocoupler outputs can I stack in series?

Tags: opto-isolator

I have 44 devices - each which provides a 5V output when active and operating correctly and 0V when not.

On my microprocessor, I need to check if all 44 are active or not (don't need to know if individual devices are active or not, but just to know that all are active or not.) I have used optocouplers to try and achieve this for a small number of devices (4) and it seems to be working. My circuit is as below.

[image]

My questions are:

1. How many optocouplers can I put in series here? Based on my limited knowledge of circuits, I believe the LED on the PC817 input side drops 1.1V and each transistor on the output side of the PC817 drops 0.7V. Does this mean I can theoretically put 12 optocouplers here?
2. How do I go about calculating the value of R2?

Based on the maximum number of device inputs I can "stack" for each microprocessor input, I will know the total pins I need on my microprocessor for the complete 44 device inputs.

EDIT: Many responses are asking if isolation is required and the answer is yes. That is a must as the inputs are all on different grounds.

Comment: Why are you using optocouplers? Do the inputs have to be isolated from the microprocessor?  Your circuit is a backhanded, overly complicated AND gate that doesn't scale very well.

Comment: Not only what JRE asked, why two in series? Your top-right one shares ground on both sides so you can replace it with a transistor if you need to translate from 12 to 3.3 V.

Comment: @JRE Yes I absolutely do need isolation here! Hence the optocouplers.

Comment: @winny You are right the top right optocoupler can be replaced with a transistor but this part is already present on my existing microcontroller custom PCB so I have not changed it.

Comment: I see. It may hurt your overall CTR since you both have 44 in series and the worst one will set your limit, then that one in series with the top-right one.

Comment: It is like wired AND. Why just do not use logical AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vf = 1.2V out of 5V input gives 3.8V drop across each input resistor, or 8mA.  Fig. 12 here gives the saturation characteristic:

https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf

about 0.1-0.5V depending on Ic.  If we say 2mA is required, then it's in the 0.1-0.2V range, and out of 12V, less the 1.2V needed for the output opto, less a couple volts for a current limiting resistor*, probably 20 in series will do fine.

*We might go further and assert that the Vce(sat)s have resistance too.  Evidently on the order of (0.5V)/(5mA) = 100 ohms each.  Which means 20 in series will be a pretty reasonable 2kohms, without any extra resistance needed.  I wouldn't feel bad "abusing" this property: even at maximum CTR, current flow won't be dangerous, and you can always add in a little resistance to keep it safe (say to limit any one transistor's worst case Pd to ratings).  Probably this allows shrinking the resistor such that 30 in series will behave.

Mind, this is a typical curve, and the worst case / minimum condition will be much worse than this.  Grades are available with different CTR ranges, which can make this a bit more consistent.

Note that optos are dreadfully slow, expect several microseconds turn-on and a hundred or so turn-off.  No problem for a basic indicator or whatever, but also practically an eternity to most CPUs for example.

As for need: are these channels all on separate grounds?  None can be joined?  Not that a common-ground logic circuit is all that much simpler (an array of 74HC30s, say?), or greatly cheaper as discrete implementation (44 diodes, lower parts cost perhaps, but a ton more parts!), so the use of optos is not particularly objectionable here, but they're usually a poor choice when a simpler solution is available.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and link to the relevant figure in the datasheet. It has cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How many optocouplers can I put in series here? Based on my limited knowledge of circuits, I believe the LED on the PC817 input side drops 1.1V and each transistor on the output side of the PC817 drops 0.7V. So does this mean I can theoretically put 12 optocouplers here?

No, theoretically, you could put much more, they will be on saturated state, and voltage drop on collector-emitter path is saturation voltage or close
2. According datasheet - you may put in count saturation voltage, or calculate roughly, like 0.1*12 = 1.2V drop on all the transistors